# Setting a custom frame buffer in media player for streaming over the wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, video

I currently use DAUM PLayer (Pot Player) but I have problems streaming video to my laptop unless it is plugged into the network by wire. An easy fix (so I thought) would be to find a player were I could adjust the cache / buffer so say 5 mins+ is read to the local Hdrive and then  played from there.

I can not work out how to do this in any player. I have VLC, MPCHC and DAUM installed.

I want to increase the file buffer so X amount of the network file is copied to the local drive and then played, so that all stuttering is stopped.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In VLC open preferences, show all options, input/codecs, scroll down to advanced, adjust network buffers. Times are in millisecs, so 10000 means 10 secs.